# Is there a clear cut method for cutout on structural members?

Tags: aircraft-structures, fuselage, books

I have been looking into fuselage cutouts especially, window cutouts on the skin panel for a school project. Reading Bruhn and Niu Books, both state that there are no clear cut methods for fuselage cutout yet before elaborating on methods based on empirical data. Is it due to the complexity that there is still no equation that may govern the shear flow direction and distribution around the cutout. Just a philosophical question I suppose, is there any other reason that may be a hindrance to from developing equation that is the "clear cut" method for cutouts. What are the mathematical/numerical methods used in this supercomputer era to properly simulate this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The reason there's no straightforward equation for fuselage cutouts is because it's a really complicated problem. Fuselage structures are complex, and when you cut a hole in them, figuring out how the stress and forces are distributed is tough. It depends on the shape of the hole, the materials used, and how the airplane is loaded. Engineers use a mix of real-world testing, computer simulations, and their experience to design planes with cutouts. It's not that we don't understand it; it's just a really tricky puzzle to solve.

Comment: A lot of the books analyze the distribution of shear flow stress due to the cutout. However, I was wondering since we are essentially removing area from the structure wouldn’t the tensile capabilities on the structure also be affected? Is there a relationship between tensil and shear capabilities of a structure?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the use of metal skins here.

Window cutouts can be made by *machining* with a rotating tool, *cutting* with a saw blade, *shearing* with powered scissors, *punching* in a powered die-cutting press, or *chem-milling* by applying a protective paint to the sheet metal everywhere you do not want a hole or cutout and then dipping it in acid to eat away the exposed holes.

The tooling required to perform these tasks varies greatly and so the method chosen will depend on the number of parts you intend to make, across which the tooling setup costs can be amortized. For a one-off plane like a homebuilt, you'll use shears or a saw and guide the process by hand. Mass production justifies punching, machining or chem-milling.

The method used will determine things like the *fatigue lifetime* of the resulting part. Shearing leaves microscopic *stress risers* in the form of microcracks at the end of each "snip" in the cutout profile whereas chem-milling leaves the cutout atomistically smooth all the way around.

Fuselage cutouts in the first revision of the De Havilland Comet were sheared and the resulting stress raisers caused premature fatigue failure of the pressure hull, which is why Boeing developed the chem-milling process to make the rivet holes and window cutouts in the 707.